# Wordpress: Display all pages

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

i want to display all pages in Wordpress in a Shortcode.
My Code looks like this:

```
function createTilesFromSites() {
$args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'exclude' => '',
    'include' => '',
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
    'authors' => '',
    'child_of' => 0,
    'parent' => -1,
    'exclude_tree' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'offset' => 0,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$pages = get_pages($args);
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
    $slug = $page_data->post_name;
    echo "$title <br />";
}
}
add_shortcode('createTiles', 'createTilesFromSites');
```

Now, it displays me the pages (my pages are called "1", "2", "3", "4" and "Blog"). So it's supposed to give me something like: "1234Blog". 
It prints me this, but not only one time. **It does it 2658 TIMES** (at least chrome says it with cmd+f, anyway, it's super long). So my output looks like this: "1234Blog1234Blog1234Blog1234Blog1234Blog1234Blog1234Blog1234Blog1234Blog1234Blog" eg.

Is something wrong with the code? Is this probably an issue with my Wordpress Setup?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's important to return, not echo, the shortcode output. Declare `$output = '';` at the start of your function, concatenate items during the loop, e.g. `$output .= $title;` and finally return the output: `return $output;`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i'm actually pretty new to php and wordpress :/ But it doesn't solve my Problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your apply_filters code will be calling your shortcode again so it will be in a loop.   So you could try to just get the content without applying filters, or strip out the shortcode from the content, or call remove_shortcode('createTiles');

Comment: Oh, you are right! But, apparantly, i need the content as well :/ How do i solve this?

Comment: Get the content

    $content = $page_data->post_content;

then search and replace your [createTiles] short code with empty string

and then call 

   $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);

Comment: What do you mean by replacing [createTiles] with empty string? Sorry i'm really new to all this :/     edit: Nvm i understood it after testing it :> Thank you!